# Angular bootstrap tour - backdrop covering nav elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [Angular Bootstrap Tour](https://github.com/benmarch/angular-bootstrap-tour) to create a tour, and am having trouble with the backdrop hiding an element on the navbar that needs to be highlighted as part of the tour.  This is what the code looks like:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" tour-step order="1" placement="bottom" backdrop="true" content="Content goes here">
            <li>
                <a href="#/">Link Goes Here</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

I've tried to change the position to static and the z-index to auto of all the elements in the same stack as the tour step, but no avail.  I've also tried to bring down the z-index of the tour backdrop and container, but nothing seems to be giving me the effect required.  Any help is greatly appreciated!